# How to prevent infinite loop in useEffect using Object from Redux store as dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I am relatively new to React, so probably it will be an easy answer for some of you.

I have bumped into a little problem, I have solved it, but it doesn't seem to be perfect as React Eslint is not happy.

My web-app is using React-Redux at the front and Node-Express-Mongo at the back. So, I have a functional component (screen/page), and whenever logged in user visits it, it needs to update user data state in Redux store to make sure it matches current data in database.

However, not registered and not logged in users also can visit that page, then obviously that database check is not needed.

I get user data as `userInfo` object from Redux:

```
const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
const { loading: loadingUser, error: errorUser, userInfo } = userLogin;
```

Then, when component renders `useEffect()` hook shoots, I dispatch an action to get user data from backend (DB) using JWT token.

```
useEffect(() => {
    //update user details in case if access to restricted services changes
    if (userInfo && userInfo.token) {
      dispatch(refreshUser(userInfo.token));
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

As you can see I kept dependency array empty, and disabled it for eslint to keep Mr Eslint happy.

So far this is the only way I can make it work. If I put `userInfo` into dependency array - it creates infinite loop, because as we know `{}==={}` always returns `false`.

If I get rid of `userInfo` from `useEffect()` and keep just `userInfo.token`, but then it creates an error `userInfo is undefined` whenever user is not logged in

Of course I can populate Redux store with some initial state of empty `userInfo` or empty `userInfo.token`, but that seems to be unnecessary hassle. I also tried to put useEffect inside `if (userInfo){}` statement, but that was just silly, as `useEffect()` should stay at the top level...

As it is now, it does what I need it to do - runs just once as the component (page) loads.

So my question is:
Is it OK to leave it like that or there must be some elegant solution?

Comment: `[userInfo]` in your dependency array will trigger recursion, because the useEffect hook itself updates `userInfo`. If you want to check `userInfo.token` with `userInfo` being potentially undefined, use `userInfo?.token` (optional chaining).

Comment: Another solution is to use the null object pattern, e.g., a `userInfo` that's *defined*, but doesn't contain a token. Depending on requirements this can confer other benefits as well.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for this syntax, useful to know. However in my case it solves only half a problem, it prevents infinite loop, but I would still need to include userInfo.token in dependency array and in case of non-logged-in user it will throw an error about userInfo is null.

Comment: @DaveNewton In case of non-logged-in user it will throw an error about userInfo is null. Thanks for your comment. I think my best bet is to keep it as it is.

Comment: I didn't say "use `null`", I said "use the null-object pattern" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) where there's a user object that represents a not-logged-in user.